# `$getjson` from Django to javascript doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

In the javascript file, I have the function below. This function performs by `a.onclick`. the "confirm" appears.

```
var delete_req = function()
    {
    var r=confirm("This requirement will be deleted!");
    if (r==true)
    {
        id = $("#reqName").attr("name");
        $.getJSON("/delete_req/",{
            id:id
        },
        function(res){
            var name = res['name'];
            alert("requirement:" + name + "had been deleted");
        });
    }
};
```

In the URLs:

```
url(r'^delete_req/$', 'main.views.delete_req'),
```

In the views:

```
def delete_req(request):
if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "get":
    id = request.get['id']
if id:
    try:
        req = requirement.objects.get(id=id)
    except requirement.DoesNotExist:
        req = None
else:
    req = None
if req:
    resp = {'name': req.name}
    req.delete()
    return HttpResponse(urllib.urlquote.json.dumps(resp), mimetype="application/json" )
else:
    resp = {'name': None}
    return HttpResponse(urllib.urlquote.json.dumps(resp), mimetype="application/json" )
```

**I don't arrive to the view function.**

**(when i put there simple print statement, it had not performed).**

**I added the urllib.urlquote, but it didn't help.**

**Do you have another idea?**

**Thanks for any reply.**

Comment: Please explain in more detail what it is that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `urllib.urlquote` on dumped json string.